# List of generic hashmaps

Tags: java, generics, casting, generic-programming

It is possible in Java to do something like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> variable = myObject.getValue(List<HashMap<String, String>>);
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> variable2 = myObject.getValue(List<HashMap<String, Integer>>);
```

instead of this:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> variable = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) myObject.getValue();
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> variable2 = (List<HashMap<String, Integer>>) myObject.getValue();
```

I know that you can cast object to specific type, but what about list of generic hashmaps?

MyObject class value can be any type.
I want to get value of specific type without casting it outside getValue() method.

I know that first one doesn't compile, so I want to know if it is possible to do something like this, instead of casting it to specific type outside getValue() method.

**EDIT:**
Second one fixed, now it can be compiled.

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing the first over the other?

Comment: Neither the first example not the second would compile, so the answer is no. Why don't you try by yourself?

Comment: This looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Some libraries like gson use TypeToken<Type> so maybe your real use-case also provide ready solutions.

Comment: When you're dealing with container of container of something you may want to look into creating a new class for this.

Comment: I suspect you may be looking for generic method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) where result type can be inferred based on argument or on reference which should hold result. But that still is only a guess without any more specific example.

Comment: Thanks, that's something what I was searching for.